# How to get the feedback of DB insert laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

my database insert query is as follows

```
DB::table('job_details')->insert([
    'job_id'        => $jobId,
    'item_id'       => $itemId,
    'type_id'       => $typeId,
    'qty'           => $qnty,
    'laminating'    => $laminating,
    'mat_id'        => $matId,
    'rates'         => $rates,
    'sqft'          => $sqft,
    'ups'           => $ups,
    'master_qty'    => $masterQnty
]);
```

and I want to get the status if the query was successful or failed.

Comment: `$results = DB::..........` [See the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#running-queries)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The insert `method` return a `boolean` you can save the result in a variable and check if the result is true.

```
$queryState = DB::table('job_details')->insert([...])
if($queryState) {
    // the query succeed
} else {
    // the query failed
}
```

Comment: but if there is an exception thrown then whole thing breaks.. right ?

Comment: what is the output if the query execution is failed?

Comment: You can see the return type  here [Database/Query/Builder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/60d469ea1dafc1c1f59016971e134cfd88d54684/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2512)

Answer (score 1):

While performing the DB operations in laravel the method will return a response either true or false also for catching exceptions you can keep the code in try catch block.

```
 try{
         $response= DB::table('job_details')->insert([
            'job_id'        => $jobId,
            'item_id'       => $itemId,
            'type_id'       => $typeId,
            'qty'           => $qnty,
            'laminating'    => $laminating,
            'mat_id'        => $matId,
            'rates'         => $rates,
            'sqft'          => $sqft,
            'ups'           => $ups,
            'master_qty'    => $masterQnty
        ]);
         if($response)
            echo 'Query was successfull';
        else
            echo 'There was some error';
    }catch{
        print_r($e->getMessage);
    }
```